# Trojan satellites

Tags: trojan-asteroids

*By extension, any object in this kind of orbit has also become known as a Trojan, so Mars, Uranus and Neptune all have Trojans of their own. Earth's first Trojan, the asteroid 2010 TK, was identified in 2011. **Saturn's moons Tethys and Dione, meanwhile, share their own orbits with Trojan satellites**.*

Let me understand the last sentence(Saturn's moons Tethys...).

In this context, what the Trojan satellites is?

Comment: Look Wikipedia! "Trojan (astronomy)" "Unlike trojan minor planets that share the orbit with a planet, a trojan moon is a moon orbiting near the trojan point of another, larger moon. All known trojan moons are part of the Saturn system. Telesto and Calypso are trojans of Tethys, and Helene and Polydeuces of Dione."

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question demonstrates no preliminary research.

Answer (score 2):

I post an answer from the comment. 
Trojan satellites or trojan moon are natural satellites that are in the lagrangian point (L4 and L5) of another bigger (more massive) moon. All the known examples are Saturn's moon. In particular Tethys and Dione have other moon in their lagrangian point L4 and L5